# Is it possible to find out who installed an extension update?

Tags: drupal, api, extension

One of my clients had the API v4 extension updated to 4.3.0 last evening, and so today the contact summary screen was broken - because the API extension isn't compatible with the contact summary extension in 5.10.4.  Is there any way of finding out who installed the extension update?  Some log somewhere?  This is a Drupal site, by the way.  One thought (maybe silly!) - the extension wouldn't update itself after a given time, would it?

Answer (score 3):

The extension wouldn't update itself.

If you have Detailed Logging enabled, you should be able to figure out who updated it by checking `log_user_id` in `log_civicrm_extension`.  If you don't have that:

- Check the "last action" times in the Drupal "Users" list.  Is there only one person who was active?  Great!
- Check your web server logs for the URL that updates the extension - something like https://mysite.org/civicrm/admin/extensions?action=update&id=net.ourpowerbase.sumfields&key=net.ourpowerbase.sumfields

You should be able to get an IP address, which, depending on whether folks access the site from one IP or not, should be able to give you your answer.

Comment: Thanks, Jon. I found a website log entry which revealed an IP address. An over enthusiastic user with too much access had done this. Access now reduced!